# Please explain powershell script error on specific code line

Tags: powershell

I have getting error on this below line in `.ps1` file.

**Code:**

```
Import-Csv $csvPath `| ? { $_.Datum -ne $date } `| Export-Csv $csvTempPath -NoTypeInformation
```

**Error:**

```
Import-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '?'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem. It is spacing issue, i have added one space between tilde and pipe sign.

```
Import-Csv $csvPath ` | ? { $_.Datum -ne $date } ` | Export-Csv $csvTempPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Now it is works fine. Thanks!